# trigger click action on url should not open the link or stay reload on my same page just want to do click on backend

Tags: javascript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 

var c = new sforce.SObject("service_request__c"); 
c.id = "{!Service_Request__c.Id}"; 
c.status__c = "sent to customer";
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
if(dd<10) { 
dd='0'+dd 
} 
if(mm<10) { 
mm='0'+mm 
} 
today =yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+ dd;  
c.sentdate__c=today;
var a="{!Service_Request__c.Nicomatic_request_Id__c}".replace(",","");
result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
location.reload();
window.open("http://www.nicomatic.com/_1new_website/index.php?action=ProcessReq3&idd="+a)
```

I want to trigger click on the url  `http://www.nicomatic.com/_1new_website/index.php?action=ProcessReq3&idd="+a` .I dont want to open in new window .I am working salesforce javascript button we can use only javascript. help me how can io trigger click on it url its should open a new window/tab.

they are two url are there one is my current page url and other is "http://www.nicomatic.com/_1new_website/index.php?action=ProcessReq3&idd="+a" i want to click this url and stay reload on my first page.i  just want the click action is done on that url .i dont want to open that link in same window or other window.

Comment: `window.open("http://www.nicomatic.com/_1new_website/index.php?action=ProcessReq3&idd="+a, "_self")` , add second parameter `"_self"`

Comment: may be what you need is a cron job...